# Rails / Omniauth Google API - refreshing a token

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-api, oauth-2.0, omniauth

This one is a little above my pay grade, so hopefully someone here can help!

I'm using the https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2 gem along with Omniauth in a Rails app. A user can successfully connect through Google and grab the permissions I need. It then returns the Auth and Refresh tokens, which I am storing.

My issue is, I can't figure out how to refresh the token when it expires. This is detailed in-depth in the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline

But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use Omniauth to check if the current token has expired, request a new one using the refresh token if so and store it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This one is also a little above my pay grade, however, I think I might be helpful. I won't submit this as an answer, because it really isn't one. But little Pro Tip™: search for your problem in the issues of the github repository, you can almost always find something interesting. I found these two issues: https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2/issues/37 and https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth2/issues/40